# Accelerometer data very jerky (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, accelerometer

When using accelerometer data to control movement, it is very jerky.

Using the [sensors plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors).

Would like to have it smooth, but reactive.

```
double x;
accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
  x = 3 - event.x;
  if (x < 0) x = 0;
  if (x > 6) x = 6;
  posX = x * screenWidth / 6;
});
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @intraector Not really, no.